# c# haversine implementation gives different answer than googlemaps/movable-type.co.uk

Tags: c#, haversine

I need to calculate the distance between two points (given latitude & longitude). I implemented the standard haversine formula in C#

```
private double toRadian(double val)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) *    
}

public double Distance(Position pos1, Position pos2,DistanceType type)
{
        double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6378137; // 6318137 in meters

        double dLat = toRadian(pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude);
        double dLon = toRadian(pos2.Longitude - pos2.Longitude);

        double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.Cos(this.toRadian(pos1.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(this.toRadian(pos2.Latitude)) *
        Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2);

        double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a)); 
        double d = R * c;

        return d;   
}
```

But I get different answers from the code and in the website http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.
For example for the input: `pos1.Latitude = 12.916822` and `Pos1.Longitude = 77.599816`
and pos2.Latitude = 12.917135 and Pos2.Longitude = 77.585783
my program returns 34.843 (when I do a `Math.Round((dist), 4)` on the answer) where as the website gives 1.521 Kms
Can anyone please point out whats wrong ?
PS: My program calculates distance in meters.

Answer (score 5):

As I'm quickly looking at it, this should be an easy fix. How about changing the following:

```
double dLon = toRadian(pos2.Longitude - pos2.Longitude);
```

... into:

```
double dLon = toRadian(pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude);
```

Notice the pos1/pos2 typo? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your implementation to use the builtin dotnet one provided on [`GeoCoordinate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is probably better tested than your implementation.